# looping or round robin assignment in php

Tags: php

I have a Customers and Employees table:

```
Customers
    .account_no
    .zipcode
-----------------------
account_no  |  zipcode
-----------------------
1111000100  |  12345
1222000100  |  25678
1333000100  |  47890
1444000100  |  50000
1555000100  |  53456
1666000100  |  63987
```

---

```
Employees
    .id_e
    .zipcode_a
    .zipcode_b
    .card_id
---------------------------------------------
id_e  |  zipcode_a  |  zipcode_b  |  card_id
---------------------------------------------
1     |   10000     |   64000     |  1011
2     |   10000     |   54000     |  1002
3     |   50000     |   64000     |  1003
```

Let say I have 6 Customers, 3 Employees; query result will be like this:

```
---------------------------------
account_no  |  zipcode  |   id_e
---------------------------------
1111000100  |    12345  |     2
1111000100  |    12345  |     1
1222000100  |    25678  |     2
1222000100  |    25678  |     1
1333000100  |    47890  |     2
1333000100  |    47890  |     1
1444000100  |    50000  |     2
1444000100  |    50000  |     3
1444000100  |    50000  |     1
1555000100  |    53456  |     2
1555000100  |    53456  |     3
1666000100  |    63987  |     3
1666000100  |    63987  |     1
```

I would like to assign these customers account to each employees in looping or round robin to look something like this:

```
---------------------------------
account_no  |  zipcode  |   id_e
---------------------------------
1111000100  |    12345  |     2
1222000100  |    25678  |     1
1333000100  |    47890  |     2
1444000100  |    50000  |     1
1555000100  |    53456  |     3
1666000100  |    63987  |     1
```

I have been  trying using usual looping but the result is random and not desirable.

Any ideas, people?

Comment: What is the algorithm for the round robin assignment?  Usually, this refers to something like 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, etc.

Comment: @GordonLinoff That's why, I just think with round robin method probably could do such an example that I want. No?

Answer (score 0):

You can make an array and override the previous key to make it so every zip code just loads the last id_e to have it for example:

if you create an array with $myarray = array();
and in your query when you import the values from your database into your array... I would give you the code for that but I do not see how you are importing it; if you show that I can help you properly format it for this case.

Then this is where you override duplicate cases of zipcodes and only take the last id_e with that same zipcode.
    foreach($myarray as $zipcode => $id_e){
    $myarray[$zipcode] = $id_e;
    }

Also I assume you currently are but make sure your mysql query includes " ORDER BY id_e" at the end of it.

Comment: Do you mean the query?
What I try:
$query = "SELECT A.account_no, A.zipcode, B.id_e 
    FROM Customers A, Employees B
    WHERE A.zipcode BETWEEN B.zipcode_a AND B.zipcode_b
    ORDER BY card_id";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$data = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC){
 $acc = $data['account_no];
 $zip = $data['zipcode'];
 $id = $data['id_e'];

 $query = "INSERT INTO temporary VALUES ('$acc','$zip','$id')";
 $result = mysql_query($query);
}

I make one table for temporary to insert all values.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I edited id_e, the result from "ORDER BY card_id".

Comment: @user1986: A query is how you use PHP/MySQL to get data from a database. Ex: $my_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE some_column=somevalue SORT BY some_other_column ASC"); This guide can help http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp

Comment: @user1986: Assuming you not knowing what I meant by query; what exactly did you mean by a 'table'... Did you mean a datatable you made in a database hosted at some place like MySQL... or a html table like <table><tr><td>My table</td></tr></table>?

Comment: Oh, the table means here is from database, not html table.